# Is there a way to select files that matches a certain regex with CAML?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

```
$CAMLQuery = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>  
    <Query> 
        <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>bad_file</Value></Eq></Where> 
    </Query> 
    <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields> 
</View>"
```

I have the following CAML query, but it only selects files whose name is exactly "bad_file", but doesn't select files whose name is "bad_file.json" or "bad_file.txt". Is there a way to use regex so that I can select all files with the substring "bad_file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for regex within CAML, but there is a [CONTAINS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/contains-element-query) element that if you used like

```
<Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>bad_file</Value></Contains>
```

it would have matched both "bad_file.json" and "bad_file.txt".

Also, this is a common mistake, the CAML schema is slightly different depending on where you are using it. The `<View>` element is only the parent element when you are defining the schema for a custom View.  If you are using it to execute a query programmatically through PowerShell,CSOM,JavaScript, etc., then `<Query>` should be your top-level, and the `<View>` is an optional child element.

Try this:

```
<Query><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>bad_file</Value></Contains><View Scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields></View></Query>
```

Comment: $CAMLQuery = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>  
        <Query> 
            <Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>bad_file</Value></Contains> 
        </Query> 
        <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields> 
    </View>" selects every file for some reason.

Comment: I just noticed that you fell victim to the classic blunder :) of the `<View>` vs. `<Query>` schema.  I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Hmm, it matched the folder and the json file next to the folder effectively deleting everything even though the folder name and the file name were asset-content and content.json

Comment: are you actually searching for "bad_file" or was that just an example?

Comment: I am searching for anything with bad_file as a substring like "bad_file.json", "bad_file.txt", etc.